# Eclipse Egit finds nested project that does not exist

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-pdt

I have a Bitbucket repository that I go to import and Egit is finding a nested project which should not exist.

Repository structure looks like:

- .git
- www

  - [PHP Laravel Source Code]
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- README.md

When I run import from git perspective it finds the www folder as a nested project, which is listed as a "PHP Project", but doesn't attribute the parent to a PHP nature (PHP Project).

There is no submodule in the repository so there should be no "nested" project.

I can turn off "Search for nested projects" but that doesn't help fix the problem of project not getting the PHP nature.

Any ideas if there is a setting in git, eclipse or Egit to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in eclipse:
in git perspective:
- clone the git repository
in PHP perspective:
- create PHP Project at existing location (where you cloned the git repository)
.project file will be created
- commit the .project file to GIT
next time you clone the git repository you can import directly from git perspective and have a project with PHP nature